# Javascript Arrays filter by type

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, types

i just start learn javascript and to test some array code, i end make this, there is  a better away to make a filter by type of value. (Sorry any mistake english is not my mother language).

```js
var list = ["lorem1",  "lorem2", "lorem3" , "lorem4", 1 ,2 ,3]
var number = 1
var type = typeof number
var numbers = list.filter(item => typeof item === type)
var words = list.filter(item => typeof item != type)
// Filter by value types
console.log(numbers)
console.log(words)
```

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a `string`. So you can use literal strings for filtering.

Comment: I think this question is better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And here is the full solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ew3fm8dk/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function and pass the type as argument like so:

```js
var list = ["lorem1",  "lorem2", "lorem3" , "lorem4", 1 ,2 ,3]

function filterByType(arr, type){
  return arr.filter(item=> typeof item === type)
}

const words = filterByType(list, 'string')
const numbers = filterByType(list, 'number')

console.log({words, numbers})
```